# How do I reference another table and column in another power query in Excel

Tags: excel, datatables, powerquery

I am having a hard time referencing a table and column from another query in Excel. I don't know if it is possible or not.

I have a table in Excel power query with about 18 rows. Let's call this "OriginalTable"

I have another table with new rates for certain centers. Let's call this "NewTable"

I am trying to reference the new rates from "New Table" if the centers match in "OriginalTable".

For example: If "OriginalTable".Center = "NewTable".Center then "NewTable".NewRate in the "OriginalTable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Powerquery, look up how to do a merge. Its fairly simple solution to your issues

Start off with the OriginalTable

Home .. Merge Queries ...

The OriginalTable is on top, choose NewTable from drop down on bottom

Click select the Center column on both top and bottom

Use left outer join

For operation, choose all rows

Hit ok.  Expand relevant field using arrows atop the new column and [x] selecting

Comment: Thank you so much! That saved me so much time!